# Kohana 3.3 обработка PUT запроса

Tags: put, ajax, php, kohana

Возникла проблема при отправке PUT запроса на Kohan'у
Никак не могу дозвониться в контроллер.
GET и POST запросы пропускает, а остальные не хочет - выдает 403 ошибку.
Есть подозрение что блокирует htaccess, но во всем интернете нигде не могу найти информацию по данному вопросу.

Может кто знает в чем причина?

Попробовал на глобальном сервере (на хосте) -- все работает, а на localhost не пашет

Comment: > а на localhost не пашет
Значит, дело в настройках. Скорее всего - веб-сервера.

Answer (score 1):

на гитхабе куча REST модулей для коханы, возьмите любой из них за основу или Controller_REST из кохана 3.2